# How to make a word clickable in text on React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get people to follow my twitter and discord by clicking on the words "Twitter" or "Discord" in the midst of my text. How would I do that below?

```
<p className="leading-[1.8] md:leading-[1.8] text-base md:text-xl max-w-[700px] my-9 font-secondary">
    Follow
    us on Twitter or join us in Discord to receive all pertinent news as it happens.{' '}
  </p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React <a> tag and button onClick propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668430/react-a-tag-and-button-onclick-propagation)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

React uses JSX (or TSX if you're using TypeScript), so you can use any standard HTML tags, including `<a/>` to link to things.

```html
Follow us on <a href="https://twitter.com/whatever">Twitter</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using span when nested. Little extra so that when clicked they open up on separate tabs.

```
<span> <a href="yourtwitter" target="_blank" 
rel="noreferrer"> @yourTwitter </a> </span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it plz. It works on my side.

```
//A simple link in Text to redirect an external website

<a className="leading-[1.8] md:leading-[1.8] text-base md:text-xl max-w-[700px] my-9 font-secondary" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980752/how-to-make-a-word-clickable-in-text-on-react-js/73980765#73980765" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
  Follow us on Twitter or join us in Discord to receive all pertinent news as it happens.{' '}
</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use the a tag like this:

```
<p>Follow me on <a href="yourUrl">Twitter</a></p>
```